# DatePicker works for current year 2020 and previous year 2019 but available dates for next year 2021 are not available

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

I use DatePicker to limit the selection to the first and third Wednesday of each month. It is working for 2019 and 2020 but not 2021. I think it has something to do with the computer date which is todays date but I cannot change that to see if I am correct.

I am using the following code which is working for 2019 and 2020 but not 2021.

Please help.

```
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script><script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link href="/resources/demos/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() { 
 var availableDates = ["6-3-2019","20-3-2019","3-4-2019","17-4-2019","1-5-2019","15-5-2019","5-6-2019","19-6-2019","3-7-2019","17-7-2019","7-8-2019","21-8-2019","4-9-2019","18-9-2019","2-10-2019","16-10-2019","6-11-2019","20-11-2019","4-12-2019","18-12-2019","1-1-2020","15-1-2020","5-2-2020","19-2-2020","4-3-2020","18-3-2020","1-4-2020","15-4-2020","6-5-2020","20-5-2020","3-6-2020","17-6-2020","1-7-2020","15-7-2020","5-8-2020","19-8-2020","2-9-2020","16-9-2020","7-10-2020","21-10-2020","4-11-2020","18-11-2020","2-12-2020","16-12-2020","06-01-2021","20-01-2021","03-02-2021","17-02-2021","03-03-2021","17-03-2021","07-04-2021","21-04-2021","05-05-2021","19-05-2021","02-06-2021","16-06-2021","07-07-2021","21-07-2021","04-08-2021","18-08-2021","01-09-2021","15-09-2021","06-10-2021","20-10-2021","03-11-2021","17-11-2021","01-12-2021","15-12-2021"];

function available(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
    return [true, "","Available"];
  } else {
    return [false,"","unAvailable"];
  }
}

$('#datepicker5').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: available,
                             maxDate: '+1Y'});
          });
```

Comment: To clarify I believe it does not work because the computer date is 2020 and 2021 is a future year but the code I am using is looking at past and current year. Maybe I am completely off base??

Comment: The values in *availableDates* for 2021 use two digit months (e.g. "19-05-2021") but other dates and your formatting don't pad single digit months and  "19-05-2021" !=  "19-5-2021".

Comment: Thank You RobG,, works perfectly.